# No module named 'xmpp' although xmpppy is installed

Tags: python, python-import

Following line in Python script

```
import xmpp,sys
```

causes an error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xmpp'
```

although xmpppy has been installed with

```
pip install xmpppy
```

I thought that may be I installed the module in one Python version and am running the script in the other Python version, but `print(sys.version)` prints the same version as `python --version` from CentOS command line.

Are there some other chances to get it work?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import xmpp,sys

xmpp_jid = 'me@jabber.server'
xmpp_pwd = 'hackme'

to = sys.argv[1]
msg = sys.argv[2]

jid = xmpp.protocol.JID(xmpp_jid)
client = xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain(),debug=[])
client.connect()
client.auth(jid.getNode(),str(xmpp_pwd),resource='xmpppy')
client.send(xmpp.protocol.Message(to,msg))
client.disconnect()
```

Comment: For example, if you use the command `python script.py` to run your script, then use `python -m pip install xmpppy` to ensure the pip used is for the same Python interpreter you're using.

Comment: I am using a text file with `#!/usr/bin/env python` header line.

Comment: `python -m pip install xmpppy` should still be the appropriate command in that case cause the name of it is `python`.

Comment: Thank you. That got me a little further.